# PhpStorm Live Edit

Tags: phpstorm

Вот уже 2 дня пробую настроить live редактирование в phpstorm. 
То есть, что бы когда я меняю что то в браузере - оно сразу в код переносилось. Читал что такое можно сделать, но у меня все никак не выходит.

И еще - можно ли сделать автообновление браузера? То есть, когда я что то сменил в коде - браузер сразу обновился?

Comment: для второго случая я использую gulp

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f__tQKkWodw 
загуглилось сразу...

Comment: `когда я что то сменил в коде - браузер сразу обновился?` - можно, но я бы не рекомендовал. Ибо на каждый чих обновлять браузер... если это не верстка чего-либо, а, например, php или js да еще с работой с БД - то это боль, каждый раз после строчки кода ожидать автоматической перезагрузки.  уж лучше вручную обновить в браузере в случае необходимости... опять же если это не верстка или же не простенький скрипт..... по поводу изменений в браузере сразу перенос в код .... тоже боль может возникнуть еще та...если откатить изменение не сможешь.

Comment: Вот хорошая статья по настройке LiveEdit в PhpStorm http://nikovit.ru/blog/live-edit-dlya-phpstorm-poleznyy-instrument-verstalshchika-/

Answer (score 0):

Автообновление браузера при редактировании кода (HTML, CSS, etc.) возможно с использованием Live Edit - см. https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Live+Edit+in+PhpStorm. Он работает из редактора в браузер, но не наоборот:( Поддержки автообновлений кода при редактировании в браузере нет (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-9557 - запрос на добавление соотв. функциональности). Точнее, есть plugin [CSS-X-Fire](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/plugin/5348-css-x-fire), но он работает только в FireFox